# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' (Many of the other questions asked weren't applicable)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've seen this Error asked on here a few times but the solutions really weren't clear to me.

I am just starting out with BeautifulSoup so this question may be a bit trivial.

I am looking to extract the second table in the following website:

http://www.espnfc.com/player/45843/lionel-messi?season=2015

Here is the code I am using to do so:

```
page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.espnfc.com/player/45843/lionel-messi?season=2015').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

data = []

#find the tables on the webpage
tables = soup.find_all('table')

#extract the table we will be analyzing
store = tables[1]

#extract all of the rows
rows = store.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:

    entries = row.tbody.find_all('td')
    if entries[6].string is not None:
        data.append(entries[6])
```

The Attribute Error i'm getting is pointed at `entries = row.tbody.find_all('td')`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depending on line number of the error, either `store`  or `row.tbody` is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you try to call `find_all` on the value `None`. That could be `row.tbody` for example, perhaps because there is no `<tbody>` in the actual HTML.

Keep in mind that the `<tbody>` element is *implied*. It'll be visible in your browser's DOM inspector, but that doesn't mean it is actually present in the HTML for BeautifulSoup to parse. Generally, you don't *need* to reference `<tbody>` at all, unless there is also a `<thead>` or `<tfooter>` or there are multiple `<tbody>` elements present.

Just search for the `<td>` cells directly:

```
rows = store.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:    
    entries = row.find_all('td')
    if len(entries) > 6 and entries[6].string is not None:
        data.append(entries[6])
```

You could simplify this by asking for a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
rows = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(2) tr')
data = [cell
        for row in rows
        for cell in row.select('td:nth-of-type(7)') if cell.string]
```

Comment: I don't believe that works. `entries` now contains no information which doesn't make sense to me. I printed `rows[1]`and it returned the expected information but entries is returning nothing.

Comment: @madhavt: define 'nothing'. Is it an empty list? `find_all` finds elements at any level in the subtree.

Comment: @madhavt: just tested the first snippet; if there are `th` header cells `entries` *should* be empty. It works for any row with `td` cells.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes it is an empty list. I've noticed that when I run `print entries[6].string` outside of my for loop, it returns the correct value but when I run the same code inside of the for loop, I am getting a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: @madhavt: not all `tr` rows have `td` cells. The first has `th` header cells.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, now i'm seeing that. Would recommend I remove that row then proceed?

Comment: `rows = store.tbody.find_all('tr')[2:]` this ended up working for me

Comment: @madhavt: glad that worked for you! Note that you don't need to slice if you simply test if there are enough `entries` found for a row; that is what my answer does.